# Ember.js production deployment issue with ember-cli-simple-auth-devise

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower, ember-cli

I am new to Ember.js and am working on an app with ember-cli-simple-auth-devise. It's working just fine in production, but when I deploy to production I get the following errors in console:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function vendor-dcea5bee9241c862bf2e30c2d2760f2e.js:15

Uncaught Error: Could not find module simple-auth-devise/initializer

This is a gist of my conf/environment.js
[https://gist.github.com/gordonbisnor/b65f192392029fe703a1]

Not sure what other code might be relevant to include for reference, but would be happy to create gists, etc.

Wondering if anybody has an idea what could cause this to be working in development but not production.

Comment: This is not a configuration issue but must have to do sth. with your infrastructure. I assume you're using Ember CLI? You probably installed the Ember CLI Addon? Did you run the generator?

Comment: Yes, using ember-cli and ember-cli-simple-auth-devise. I started developing locally, had no environment specific information, everything worked. I tried to setup different API locations for dev vs production (localhost:3000 vs production API) and deploy production - this is when I started seeing the error. I then tried reverting to just the default development environment and deploying that -- worked fine. So there's either something about how I am attempting to distinguish/deploy the production settings, or something that is beyond me in the  workings of Bower/npm/ember-cli etc. I'm guessing?

Comment: As long as Ember Simple Auth is registered in your `bower.json` file, it should be available regardless of whether it's running in the development or production environment.

Comment: In Firefox I see a different error message: Ember.Handlebars.compile is not a function; then the same simple-auth-devise message: Uncaught Error: Could not find module simple-auth-devise/initializer.

Comment: I tried using another randomly named environment, so "development", and "foobar" instead of "production" -- and had no problems. So either there's something wrong with my app (error that shows up in concatenation? some config that I have omitted?), that only shows up when ember-cli does the production build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be removing [ember-cli-bootstrap](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-cli-bootstrap), see [this Githuib issue in ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1727) and [this Github issue in bootstrap-for-ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember/issues/168).

Comment: Could you expand on this please? I'm having the same problem now. Does this mean I have to get rid of bootstrap-for-ember and use somehthing else?

Comment: Vida -- sorry it's been a while and my memory is a bit foggy, but looking at my code yes at the time I removed ember-cli-bootstrap, and installed with Bower. https://gist.github.com/gordonbisnor/e719c95b2e690a9b8903 – please understand that (A) I am probably as far from as an Ember expert as one could get and (B) given how quickly Ember.js is moving whatever issue I had may have been resolved or better solutions become available, etc!

Comment: Gordon, thanks very much for taking the time to come back to this.I just spent weeks learning ember and getting a project together and then this happens.. sheesh..